# jQuery (JS) error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: If

Tags: javascript, jquery, referenceerror

I keep getting this

> "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: If"

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var row_count = 1;
            var row_tbody = $(".rows").find('tbody');
            var add_row_btn = $(".add_row");
            var rmv_row_btn = $(".rmv_row");

            $(add_row_btn).click(function() {
                $(row_tbody).append('<tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>');
                $(row_tbody).append('');
                $(row_tbody).append('');
                $(row_tbody).append('');
                row_count++;
            });


                    $(rmv_row_btn).click(function() {
                        If(row_count != 1)
                            $(".rows").find('tbody').find('tr').last().remove();
                });

        });
```

I have searched around and what I found on this error was that people:

- Forgot to include jQuery lib
- Declared the variable in an out of scope place
- Missed a curly brace or a parenthesis
- Misc. (from my poorly experienced eyes, the other questions/answers weren't relevant.

But these don't seem to be the problem for me (from what I can see)

So I usually prefer to find the answer instead of asking for it but I have been stuck here for a while and therefore I'm asking here. I hope I won't get scolded for missing some obvious norm (this is my first time asking).

Thanks

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. It should be `if`, not `If`. See the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: I cant believe I didn't notice this. Thank you everyone. //Been coding VBA all day at work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have error in line

```
If(row_count != 1) // If with big letter I
```

change it to

```
if(row_count != 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please change the case of

```
If(row_count != 1)
```

to

```
if(row_count != 1)
^
```

Answer (score 1):

`If` is not recognized. Use lowercase `if` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `If` is a typo. You meant to write `if` (note the capitalization).

Like so:

```
if (row_count != 1) {
  $(".rows").find("tbody").find("tr").last().remove();
}
```

Here is a working example of what you are trying to accomplish:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var row_count = 1;
  var row_tbody = $(".rows").find("tbody");
  var add_row_btn = $(".add_row");
  var rmv_row_btn = $(".rmv_row");

  $(add_row_btn).click(function() {
    $(row_tbody).append(
      '<tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>'
    );
    $(row_tbody).append("");
    $(row_tbody).append("");
    $(row_tbody).append("");
    row_count++;
  });

  $(rmv_row_btn).click(function() {
    if(row_count != 1) {
      $(".rows").find("tbody").find("tr").last().remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add_row" type="button">Add row</button>
<button class="rmv_row" type="button">Remove row</button>

<table class="rows">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, there is a case sensitivity issue in your code snippet. 
Just change your If (as shown in the image) to if with lowercase (**i**).

[image]